# What is the difference between @Immutable and @Entity(mutable=false) when using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity, immutability

What is the difference between the two if any?

Should one or both be used on an entity?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For **entity** there's practically no difference. `@Immutable` gets priority (that is if you have entity that's annotated both as `@Immutable` and `@Entity(mutable = "true")` it is going to be treated as immutable).

`@Immutable` can also be used on collections with pretty much the same semantics. Details are [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-entity)

Comment: It's not well documented, no. `EntityBinder` source comments describe the above mentioned priority.

Answer (score 24):

The `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` annotation is deprecated and will be removed in a future release of Hibernate.

Hence, you should always use the [`@Immutabale`](https://vladmihalcea.com/immutable-entity-jpa-hibernate/) annotation if you have entities that should never be modified by Hibernate.

The `@Immutable` annotation tells Hibernate to load entities in read-only mode, hence entity modifications cannot be tracked by the dirty checking mechanism.

However, the `@Immutable` entities can still be updated via `JPQL` or [`Criteria API`](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-criteria-api-bulk-update-delete/) bulk update queries.

To make sure `@Immutabale` entities are never modified for bulk update queries, from Hibernate 5.2.17 onwards, you can set the following configuration property:

```
<property
    name="hibernate.query.immutable_entity_update_query_handling_mode"
    value="exception"
/>
```

With this property in place, a bulk update query will end up throwing an exception and the entity update will be prevented.

Comment: hi @Vlad Mihalcea - I assume I know the answer, but is there any way to have exception thrown on regular updates to @Immutable? (instead of updates just being ignored)

Comment: That's a good idea. You should open a Jira issue for it and provide a Pull Request with a fix. I'm no longer working for Red Hat, so I can't help you with this.

Comment: @VladMihalcea which @Immutable annotation to use? `org.springframework.data.annotation.Immutable` vs  `org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable`? Multumesc

Comment: @ALZ I've never seen anyone use the Spring `@Immutable` annotation. Check out the Spring code to see what it does, and then you will find the answer to your question.